# Creatign a custom binding adapter for databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am fetching a web service of a profile in which I am obtaining gender as *1- Male 2- Female and 3- Not Preferred*(Referenced). The web service gives me the value of as **1, 2, 3**.

And I am using 2-way data binding for setting up thing I had written a custom binding adapter that is throwing an error to me.

Here is Custom Binder Code

```
 @BindingAdapter({"android:gender"})
    public static String loadGender(Integer genderCode) {
        if (genderCode == 1) {
            return "Male";
        } else if (genderCode == 2) {
            return "Female";
        } else if (genderCode == 3) {
            return "Not Preferred";
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and from xml I am accepting android:gender=@{userProfile.xxxx}

But I am not getting converted value

---

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
  >   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:gender' with parameter type java.lang.String on android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText.
  >   file:D:\AndroidProjects\HMA\hma_1.0_ankit\HMA-Android\HmaApplication\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile_user.xml
  >   loc:136:42 - 136:67
  >   ****\ data binding error ****
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
19 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 15 up-to-date

---

Can someone please let me know why I am wrong

Comment: Nope. Can you guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a value from a Binding Adapter, you should rather do what you want inside of the Binding Adapter. Your method should be:

```
    @BindingAdapter("android:gender")
    public static void loadGender(TextInputEditText textInputEditText, int genderCode) {
        String gender = null;
        if (genderCode == 1) {
            gender = "Male";
        } else if (genderCode == 2) {
            gender = "Female";
        } else if (genderCode == 3) {
            gender = "Not Preferred";
        }

        textInputEditText.setText(gender);
    }
```

Data Binding will automatically pass in the TextInputEditText where you used your `android:gender` attribute.

Also, you should use your attribute as follows:

`android:gender="@{userProfile.xxxx}"` (**Note quotation marks around @{}**)

**Suggested improvement**: Because you are not overriding a native Android attribute (`android:gender` is not normally an attribute on views), I would recommend that you rather call your attribute "gender". Thus, you define your Binding Adapter with `@BindingAdapter("gender")` and reference your attribute in XML as `app:gender="@{userProfile.xxxx}"`

Comment: I have updated my answer to use EditText. Please test and let me know if you have problems.

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
  ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:gender' with parameter type java.lang.String on android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText.
  file:D:\AndroidProjects\HMA\hma_1.0_ankit\HMA-Android\HmaApplication\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile_user.xml
  loc:136:42 - 136:67
  ****\ data binding error ****

Comment: I have tested it on my side with no errors, it's working perfectly. Please update your question with your **full XML layout code** and the code where you define xxxx of `userProfile.xxxx` so that I can better help you. Are you sure `userProfile.xxxx` returns an integer?

Comment: I have updated my answer to use TextInputEditText and tested, works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174210/discussion-between-wess-and-a-tale).